# Sorting by selection in an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

so my program should be able to take several numbers from the user until the last number is "999". Then, it should be able to print out an array having all the numbers entered sorted. I have to use sorting by selection (by comparing values in each index).

I tried by best and i don't seem to know what is going wrong

this is my code: (sorry for the lack of tidiness and comments, I'm in a hurry)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    int i;
    int sentinel =999;
    int A[250];
    cout <<"Please enter the list of nbs  ending with 999"<< endl;
    cin>>n;
    i=0;
int nblist;
    while(n!=sentinel)
    {
        A[i]=n;
      cin>>n;
        i++;
    }

    nblist = i-1;
     int minindex;
    i =0;
    int min;

    int k;
    k=0;
    min=A[k];
for(k=0;k<nblist;k++)
{cout<<k<<endl; int i =0;
while(i<nblist){
        cout<<i<<endl;
         if (A[i]< min)
         {
             min= A[i];
             if (A[i]==min)
             {minindex=j;}
             i++;
            //cout<< "the array containing min is "<< minindex << endl;
         }
         cout<<"The nb of array is "<<i<<"its filled with"<< A[i]<<endl;

     }int temp;
        temp= A[k];
        A[k]=A[minindex];
        A[minindex]=temp;

     //cout<<"The nb of array is "<<k<<"its filled with"<< A[k]<<endl;
     //cout<<"The nb of array is "<<minindex<<"its filled with"<< A[minindex]<<endl;
    int counter=0;

    while(counter<nblist)
    { cout<<"The nb of array is "<<counter<<"its filled with"<< A[counter]<<endl;
       counter++;
    }
}   
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. 1. Read from standard input until entered number is 999 and store entered numbers in some container 2. Write a function which takes that container and sort the elements using selection sort algorithm then call it 3. Output sorted content. What is the exact problem? I would recommend reading some C++ book first.

Comment: you need to just sort the data right ? using selection sort ??

Comment: it is look like that you just copy paste you home work here isn't it ?

Comment: "I'm in a hurry" - *that* always goes well with trying to write code.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Pay attention in class.

Start writing assignments earlier then the deadline day.